# Failure in configuring ROS environment

Tags: ros, environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm installing Groovy on ubuntu 12.04,when I'm configuring the environment,the following error occurs,(before this command it runs smoothly )

```
bash:/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash:no such file or directory.
```

I installed Fuerte a few days ago ,but before I'm configuring the environment for Groovy ,I have uninstalled it.
I have tried to open the file to check whether it exist or not ,put the command `gedit /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` on the terminal,it was opened ,but it was empty.
What can I do to solve it ,thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147241/failure-in-configuring-ros-environment/) by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-04-01**:
gedit /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash will open with empty doc, no matter if the file exists and is empty or does not exist. Go to the path in your file system (cd /opt   cd ros   cd hydro) and check (ls) whether the file exists...

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-01**:
but how can I solve my problem to configure the ros environment successfully

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-04-01**:
Does the file or the entire folder (/opt/ros/hydro) exist? If not something might have gone wrong during sudo apt-get install or so, i. e. reinstall...

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-01**:
the entire folder (/opt/ros/hydro) does not exist, Do I have to reinstall ROS ? And I want to know the importance of the configuration of the evironment.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-04-02**:
ROS is not installed in this case, try starting again for scratch with the steps noted here http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use groovy, not hydro, you should source the file `/opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash` not `/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash`.

**Edit**:

Please open your the file `~/.bashrc` in an editor and check the lines that relate to ros (likely at the end of the file). There should be one line `source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash`. If there are multiple, or lines containting `hyrdo`, like `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash`, then remove them and try again by opening a fresh terminal.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-02**:
the following are my cammands,I followed http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu
echo "source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
when I entered the second command,error occurs,said bash:/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash:no such file or directory.I 'm confused about it.

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-02**:
thank you , the problem is solved. somenting else ,I want to know the importance of the configuration of the evironment.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
If the problem is solved, please mark one of the answers as accepted. If you have another question, open up another question. You will have to be a bit more specific than "I want to know the importance of the configuration of the evironment." though.